# Not able to upload file in the github repository

Tags: github, github-pages

I am new to GitHub and I have to submit one assignment through GitHub.

I have been reading [this blog](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/) for uploading files through github, but am not able to see any button labeled **Upload files** on my home screen of the repository

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

See the "or push an existing repository from the command line" to push existant files to your repository. You won't have to load them by a form but with your command line from your project.

Comment: cant i upload my files directly from the browser?

Comment: I don't think you can (or I'm missing something too for 3 months on Github^^)

Comment: should i have to download the github setup for the windows and try it using that?

Comment: I don't know, never tried it. I just downloaded git bash (and git obviously) and I push my commits directly to my github account by git push origin ..... I didn't install setups and it worked all alone^^ so I can't help you with it, sorry

Comment: @LijinJohn you can upload in the browser, but trust me, it's a PITA. Save yourself time and use Git or Github Desktop. Git has a GUI edition, but it's bad compared to Github Desktop. But if you still want to manually upload the files, press e.g. the readme link where it says `We recommend every repository includes a...`. Add something in there (e.g. the repo name) and the repo will be initialized. And you can upload the files

Answer (score 1):

Github does not work like cloud storage platform. You actually need to have git installed on your computer in order to be able to push code to your repositories.

1. First of all, you need to install `git`( download links [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads) ).
2. Then you need to init your local repositories with `git init`. **Caution** you need to run this command inside the directory your code is placed.
3. Run `git add --all` to stage the changes
4. Run `git commit -m "your message"` to commit your changes
5. Run `git add remote origin (repo_link or ssh)` to add your Github repo as a remote repository
6. Run `git push -u origin master` to push your `master` branch to remote `origin`

This might look a lot at first place but, you 'll get used to it **really soon**

### Alternative

You can also the [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) and [GitHub](https://desktop.github.com/) GUI which are much friendlier for a beginner.